# AngularJs Model is undefined when passing in ng-click function

Tags: angularjs

I get undefined for my logInModel when passing it in ng-click function. however when i use debugger i can see my properties are populating with value.

can someone explain to me please?

```
    $scope.logInModel = {
        userName: "",
        password: ""
    };

    $scope.postLogin = function (logInModel) {
        console.log("logInModel " + logInModel);
        authService.postLogin(logInModel).then(successCallback, errorCallBack);
    }


<div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>
            User Name:&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="txtUserName" ng-model="logInModel.userName" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>
            Password:&nbsp;
            <input type="password" name="txtUserName" ng-model="logInModel.password" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>
            <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" ng-click="postLogin(loginmodel)">
                <span> Sign In</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing postLogin(loginmodel) in your view, however in your $scope, it is logInModel, with a capital I and M that's why it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The casing is wrong in the ng-click. Use an upper case "I" and "M" ... As in logInModel

Comment: Thank you, didnt know it was case secretive

Answer (score 0):

Your passing parameter is wrong. It should be ng-click="postLogin(logInModel)"